# How to create different transition / animation delay?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a div with two other div's inside it that are positioned absolute and have a transition property.

On mouse hover i need to move the first div by changing the `bottom` property, and show the second (which has opacity 0 by default) by changing the `opacity` to 1.

The problem is that the texts show up on top of each other, so i need the second element to wait for the first element's transition and the inverse when the mouse leaves the wrapper, so i gave a transition delay to the second element, which kind of fixed this. But there is still a problem when the mouse leaves the box because of the transition delay, the second element stays visible for some time while the first element moves back to its initial position.

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; /* becomes 120px on hover */
    transition: bottom .6s ease;
}

.wrapper:hover .title{
    bottom: 120px;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0; /* becomes on hover 1 */
    transition: opacity .6s ease .6s; /* added transition delay to wait for the first element to go up */
}

.wrapper:hover .text{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, a.</div>
  </div>
```

Is there some work-around for this (without javascript) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the transition delay on hover to reverse the effect:

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: #777;
}

.title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; /* becomes 120px on hover */
    transition: bottom .6s ease .6s;
}

.wrapper:hover .title{
    bottom: 120px;
    transition: bottom .6s ease;
}

.text{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0; /* becomes on hover 1 */
    transition: opacity .6s ease 0s; /* added transition delay to wait for the first element to go up */
}

.wrapper:hover .text{
    transition: opacity .6s ease .6s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="title">My title</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, a.</div>
  </div>
```